# Populate a table from client side based upon the dates selected

Tags: javascript

I have two dates fields for *fromdate* and *todate* Based on that i want to populate a table with the dates along with the day And number of rows of the table will be equal to difference between *fromdate* and *todate*. Is it possible to do it on the client side? I mean using JavaScript? I don't want to do that on server side.

Comment: is it helpfull ? you got the info ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Calculate date diff in day](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/datedifference.shtml) ,

```
//Set the two dates
var mydate=new Date(2012, 0, 1) //Month is 0-11 in JavaScript
today=new Date()
//Get 1 day in milliseconds
var one_day=1000*60*60*24

//Calculate difference btw the two dates, and convert to days
alert(Math.ceil((today.getTime()-millennium.getTime())/(one_day)));
```

now reset is you need to create table and appedn with you body element ..

[Dynamic table creation](http://ajondeck.net/post/2010/06/24/jQuery-Dynamically-Create-Table.aspx)

```
var $wrap = $('<div>').attr('id', 'tableWrap');

            var $tbl = $('<table>').attr('id', 'basicTable');

            for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {

                $tbl.append(
                            $('<tr>')
                                    .append($('<td>').text(i),
                                            $('<td>').text(200 - i))
                           );
            }

            $wrap.append($tbl);
            $('body').append($wrap);
```

Comment: Its usefull. But can not get why 200 is used in the for loop?